# Matlab convert string "aaa" to ["a", "a", "a"] array

Tags: matlab, data-structures, string

So I'm working in Matlab and having a real problem trying to understand how strings work in Matlab.

Basically I'm trying to load a string into a double array in its binary version.

So basically i want to load "a" and get [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1] out.

I have the following below that converts a string to its binary representation but this only leads to me having "a" = ["01100001"] when I convert it to an array and [1100001] when converted to a number using str2num

```
    function loadString(obj, string)
        binaryString = reshape(dec2bin(string, 8), 1, []);

    end
```

So basically I'm looking for a way to convert a string to an array of characters ie "aaa" -> ["a" "a" "a"]. That way I convert the binaryString to ["0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"] then convert that array using str2num.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
z = dec2bin('abc',8)'
z1 = z(:)'
z2 = arrayfun(@str2double, z1)

z1 =
011000010110001001100011

z2 =
     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! I tell you, not even in C have I found a worse representation of strings

Comment: Nice, that's short and sweet. I did have fun writing my convoluted piece though :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an optimization of Rich C's version:

```
z = reshape(dec2bin('abc', 8)', 1, []) - '0'
```